# Stripe Checkout session with total price and not unit_price

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm working on a project currently. and I'm making use of stripe, the stripe.checkout.session.create function works perfectly.

```js
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  line_items: [
    {
      price_data: {
        currency: "usd",
        unit_amount: 500,
        product_data: {
          name: "name of the product",
        },
      },
      quantity: 1,
    },
  ],
  mode: "payment",
  success_url: "http://example.com/success",
  cancel_url: "http://example.com/",
});
```

but the only issue i have is it receives only unit price.

but i want a field where i can pass only total Price, cause in my code , if the users applys a discount to  a product , it deducts it from the product total price meanwhile the unit price for each product is stable.

My question is basically is there a field where i can pass total price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is that you can't. You need to use the `line_items` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items) and either pass a Price object ID (`price_xxx`) or use ad-hoc pricing with the `price_data` parameter. Checkout will then compute the total from all line items, factoring in any [discounts](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-discounts) that you provide.

You have a couple of options to achieve the behaviour you want:

- Re-calculate the `price_data.unit_amount` value to reflect the discount applied by your customers.
- Utilise Stripe [coupons](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/discounts#coupons) to apply to the Checkout Session which will take care of the dedication for you.